# Use Google Apps Script to fill out a PDF form saved on my Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have this built in Excel, but struggling to transition it to Google Sheets. I have customer information in a Sheet (name, address, services...) and a PDF which needs to be filled from this information. I saw suggestions to use DocHub, but that doesn't seem to get me there, and I need the rest of the formatting and data in the PDF, not just outputting or printing the sheet as a PDF.

So: PDF is in my Google Drive. It has editable fields. I want to fill those fields with specified data from my Google Sheet.

I'm OK with it being a script that I modify (I do a lot of scripting) or a MailMerge or an add-on or any other method.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no built-in methods for directly editing PDF file in Google Apps Script, even if the PDF file has the form which can be edited. So in your case, as one workaround, how about editing the PDF file by the binary level? But I'm not sure about your PDF file. So I'm not sure whether this can be actually used for your situation. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: I assumed it was such. How would I do the binary editing?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that these classes can be used. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities

Comment: I'll look into that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome. If you have any question, feel free to tell me.

Comment: As the current workaround (with V8 runtime), is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60523717

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the PDFFiller API](https://www.pdffiller.com/en/fill-pdf-api) or something similar. Alternatively PDFFiller have a GSheets Add-on you can use to complete a PDF template.