# Is it possible to fill in PDF forms through Google Script? Or add text on PDF through Google Script on the cloud?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, pdf-form

Now basically all our jobs are deployed on **Google Suites** and triggered through **Google Script**, so what we want is that we can add this function - **filling in the PDF forms - using Google Script** as well.

Before what we are trying to do was to design a PDF-like template using Google Sheet and by looping, updating the blank information of the form, and finally saving the result as PDF, we will have the result that we want.

However in this time, the PDF is not that easy to imitate in Google Sheet. It is from the government and thus it is better to keep their format and simply fill in the PDF form.

Actually, we've tried to use the **Excel VBA or Python on the hard drive** to do and it is pretty simple task to finish. But the problem would be wasting time to switch between platforms and it is not a good solution to deploy everything on the Cloud.

So we are wondering if there is a way to 1) filling PDF forms through Google Script? 2) Or add text on PDF through Google Script on the cloud? 3) Or do it on the cloud in general?

Comment: Please try some other StackExchange channel as this mainly related to programming/development questions and answer to your questions is subjective to different users as well.

Comment: Not impossible to do in Google apps script. But  I'm guessing and  you need to see if there are JavaScript libraries that do what you want and see if  they're compatible with apps  script.

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script does not have a native way to programatically fill in an existing PDF.

You'll have to find some 3rd party service/API, or a JavaScript library, that lets you programatically fill in an existing PDF and then you can call it or use it in GAS.

Comment: Actually you can (it should be easier now with V8), but you need to either build a custom PDF parser from the ground up or leverage an existing javascript library.

Comment: A PDF parser wont work with many form-fillable government PDF files because they are digitally signed. I have never seen/found a JavaScript library for filling PDF forms. But, like I said, if there is some API service that lets you then you could make calls to it from GAS.

Comment: @Xiau, Looking for a solution similar to this. Did you find a solution or library?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put the values in PDF form using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script? In order to test this situation, I used the following sample PDF file including PDF form.

[image]

### Usage:

In this case, first, it is required to retrieve the field names from PDF form. So, in order to put the values in the PDF form, please do the following flow.

#### 1. Retrieve field names from the PDF form

In this case, I think that this sample script in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76816468) can be used. Using this sample script, please retrieve the field names of the PDF form.

The actual script is as follows.

```js
async function myFunction1() {
  const pdfFileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID of your PDF file on Google Drive.

  // Load pdf-lib
  const cdnjs = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnjs).getContentText().replace(/setTimeout\(.*?,.*?(\d*?)\)/g, "Utilities.sleep($1);return t();"));

  const blob = DriveApp.getFileById(pdfFileId).getBlob();
  const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(new Uint8Array(blob.getBytes()));
  const form = pdfDoc.getForm();
  const { PDFTextField, PDFDropdown, PDFCheckBox, PDFRadioGroup } = PDFLib;
  const res = form.getFields().map(f => {
    const retObj = { name: f.getName() };
    if (f instanceof PDFTextField) {
      retObj.value = f.getText();
      retObj.type = "Textbox";
    } else if (f instanceof PDFDropdown) {
      retObj.value = f.getSelected();
      retObj.options = f.getOptions();
      retObj.type = "Dropdown";
    } else if (f instanceof PDFCheckBox) {
      retObj.value = f.isChecked();
      retObj.type = "Checkbox";
    } else if (f instanceof PDFRadioGroup) {
      retObj.value = f.getSelected();
      retObj.options = f.getOptions();
      retObj.type = "Radiobutton";
    } else {
      retObj.type = "Unknown";
    }
    return retObj;
  });
  console.log(res);
}
```

#### 2. Sample script

In this sample script, [pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/) is used. Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Apps Script, and set your file ID of the PDF file to `pdfFileId` and `obj`. `obj` is an array including JSON object. The values of `name` and `value` are the field name and the input value you expect, respectively.

```js
async function myFunction2() {
  const pdfFileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID of your PDF file on Google Drive.
  const obj = [
    { "name": "textbox.sample1.sample1.page1", "value": "updated1" },
    { "name": "dropdownlist.sample2.sample1.page1", "value": "sample option5" },
    { "name": "checkbox.sample3.checkbox1.page1", "value": true },
    { "name": "checkbox.sample3.checkbox2.page1", "value": false },
    { "name": "checkbox.sample3.checkbox3.page1", "value": true },
    { "name": "radiobutton.sample4.page1", "value": "radiobutton.sample4.radiobutton2.page1" }
  ];

  // Load pdf-lib
  const cdnjs = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnjs).getContentText().replace(/setTimeout\(.*?,.*?(\d*?)\)/g, "Utilities.sleep($1);return t();"));

  const blob = DriveApp.getFileById(pdfFileId).getBlob();
  const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(new Uint8Array(blob.getBytes()));
  const form = pdfDoc.getForm();
  const { PDFTextField, PDFDropdown, PDFCheckBox, PDFRadioGroup } = PDFLib;
  obj.forEach(({ name, value }) => {
    const field = form.getField(name);
    if (field instanceof PDFTextField) {
      field.setText(value);
    } else if (field instanceof PDFDropdown) {
      if (field.isMultiselect()) {
        value.forEach(v => field.select(v));
      } else {
        field.select(value);
      }
    } else if (field instanceof PDFCheckBox) {
      field[value ? "check" : "uncheck"]();
    } else if (field instanceof PDFRadioGroup) {
      field.select(value);
    }
  });
  const bytes = await pdfDoc.save();
  DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob([...new Int8Array(bytes)], MimeType.PDF, "sample.pdf"));
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is used in the above sample PDF file, the following result is obtained. In this sample, the new PDF file is created in the root folder of Google Drive.

[image]

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the pdf-lib library is loaded in the script. But, of course, in this case, you can also use the pdf-lib library by copying and pasting the script library retrieved from `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js` in the script editor of Google Apps Script. In this case, the process cost for loading it can be reduced.

#### References:

- [pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/)
- [Retrieving and Putting Values for PDF Forms using Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://medium.com/google-cloud/retrieving-and-putting-values-for-pdf-forms-using-google-apps-script-92412a7cf0af)